# Dotnet Core MVC Rewrite Reverse Proxy worked but now 404.4

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core

I have a Dotnet Core MVC application which I host on Azure.

There are three rewrite rules which reverse proxy content from another website in to the application.

Since my last deployment this broke on Azure and it has also broken on my local development environment.

I assume that there has been a patch or update as if I traverse my code and reset to an older commit the reverse proxy rules still don't work but they did before.

I have swapped my application back to the previous deployment slot and it is now working but I am unable to release any changes.

Here is my web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout">
        <environmentVariables />
      </aspNetCore>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="ProxyTrees" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^trees/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://x/trees/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="ProxyNurseries" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^nurseries/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://x/nurseries/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="ProxyCashAndCarry" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^cash-and-carry/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://x/cash-and-carry/{R:1}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Now when I visit /trees /nurseries or /cash-and-carry I get error 404.4

'The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.'

I am really stumped as usually there is a code change that causes a problem like this but i literally can't find anything.

Help appreciated!

Comment: ARR used by Azure App Service does not have proxy mode enabled by default, so you cannot use it as a reverse proxy yet.

Comment: This problem is happening on my development box (didn't previously) and also on Azure (didn't previously) so something has changed both in Azure and on my home machine.

Comment: Or something changed on `http://x/` (I just came across a similar issue). You might use failed request tracing on your local box to further analyze the issue.

Comment: See if these help? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2011/08/24/return-404-4-not-found-when-url-rewrite/, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis, https://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/ (Point #8),

Comment: Thanks for the links, will check them out today. 
Lex - nothing has changed at http://x/ - if i revert to my previous deployment on Azure the reverse proxy works, however reverting to this code on dev does not work - this is why i think it's environment (also basically nothing has changed apart from a html file)

Comment: Update: on local if I publish to a local folder, set up in IIS, install ARR, enable proxy then reverse proxy rewrites work. Unfortunately no longer work in IIS Express or in my latest Azure deployment - I guess somehow ARR / ARR Proxy is disabled in Azure by default now.... the quest continues.

Comment: Update: I have a feeling that 'ARR Proxy' is not enabled on deployment slots and therefore is not enabled on Live when you 'swap' a slot. Will test this today.
I have tried to force it enabled with application host configs but to no avail.

Comment: Final update: It turns out that when you use a deployment slot ARR Proxy is disabled, so when you swap the deployment slot with Live the disabled ARR Proxy app container becomes Live and the rewrites no longer work. The solution is to deploy directly to Live and not to swap deployment slots.